# Switch between wakelocks

Tags: android

I write application with service which periodically takes data from server,analyze them and after it launches alarm ( if it necessary), I use partial wake lock( in service) for awake device and parse json data, then I use full wake lock for awake screen at device. but it is doesn't work, how to solve this problem?
code:

```
   Autobus66WakeLock.partialLockOff(Autobus66Service.this);
   Autobus66WakeLock.lockOn(Autobus66Service.this);
```

after that this code returns false

```
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    return pm.isScreenOn();
```

lockOn method:

```
public static void lockOn(Context context) {
    LocalLog.appendLog("full lock off");
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    //Object flags;
    if (wl == null)
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "MATH_ALARM");
    wl.acquire();
}
```

lock off:

```
public static void partialLockOff(Context context){
    LocalLog.appendLog("partial lock off");
    if(pWlock != null && isPartialWakeLock){
        pWlock.release();
        isPartialWakeLock=false;
    }
}
```